# How do I get ONLY Telegram Bot's first_name using get_bot()?

Tags: telegram, telebot

I'm creating a Telegram Bot using Telebot.

```
bot.get_me()
```

`get_me()` is the same as `getme()` in Telegram Bot Api.
I need to get the bot's first name.

Code above gives me:

```json
{
   "id":5519834543,
   "is_bot":true,
   "first_name":"BOTtle",
   "username":"SomethingnotsurewhatBot",
   "last_name":"None",
   "language_code":"None",
   "can_join_groups":true,
   "can_read_all_group_messages":false,
   "supports_inline_queries":false
}
```

In Telegram Bot Api's documentation it says that `getme()` returns a JSON object: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#available-types

How do I ask it to return only `first_name` or `username`?

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't get first_name by key from that dictionary?

Comment: You can't, just parse the JSON to get the data you need/

Answer (score 0):

#### Apparently you can use regex

```
import re
import telebot


bot=telebot.TeleBot(token="ur token")
resp=str(bot.get_me())
match=re.findall("'first_name': '(.*)', 'user",resp)
print(match[0])
```

##### Here I m using telebot so regex may differ a bit as per your json response it should be like this

```
match=re.findall(r'"first_name":"(.*)"',resp)
```

###### You can refer to this regex cheatsheat for detailed regex info [here](https://www.pythontutorial.net/python-regex/python-regex-cheat-sheet/)